# git adding AND checking out in one step interactively?

Tags: linux, git

Is there combined `git add -p` / `git co -p` for the command line ? A command where I could, for each hunk, decide individually (and interactively) whether I want to stage it, revert to the committed version or leave it as it is ?

Answer (score -1):

you don't have it for `git add` but you do have it for `git commit`.

For commits is `git rerere` (its not what you asked for).

The whole concept of hunks is that it allow you  to choose what action you want to perform per change. If you want to "discard" you r changes then don't add the file, if you want to add whole the changes then add the file itself etc.